# Hey,i got a error while making an enemy ai in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity3D i created a zombie character with a simple enemy ai script so that the zombie will chase the player but when i added the NavMeshAgent component it declares the following error message:

> "SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh.UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent:SetDestination(Vector3)

I have already tried to bake the NavMesh but it did not work,please help i am stuck.
Here's my code:

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float lookRadius = 20f;
    Transform target;
    NavMeshAgent agent;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        target = PlayerManager.instance.player.transform;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);

        if (distance <= lookRadius)
        {
            agent.SetDestination(target.position);
        }
        if (distance <= agent.stoppingDistance)
        {
            FaceTarget();
        }
        void FaceTarget()
        {
            Vector3 direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
            Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z));
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * 5f);
        }
    }
    public void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, lookRadius);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this post ? https://answers.unity.com/questions/507534/setdestination-can-only-be-called-on-an-active-age-1.html

Quote : "If you create a NavMeshAgent and set its position via transform.position=... and then try to SetDestination, it fails because the NavMeshAgent did not recognize the position change and does not know that it already is on the NavMesh. Use NavMeshAgent.Warp instead of transform.position to initialize the position before calling SetDestination."

Comment: i am going to post my code please take a look.

Comment: The error is a simple one. Your unit is not already on the navmesh or it is not active. As Jonas said you need to make sure it is on the navmesh and that the navmesh agent is enabled and so on to work.

Comment: I double checked i have a NavMeshAgent on my character i have it enabled still doesn't work is it a bug in unity do i have to update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved i just had to check the ground as static and and bake the NavMeshAgent.
Hope it helps